# Inconsistent behavior of TensorReduce with assumptions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, tensors

I tried two expressions below, I wonder why the results are different.

The first is:

```
assumptions1 = {a \[Element] Vectors[2, Reals], b \[Element] Vectors[2, Reals]};
TensorReduce[(a + b).(a + b) == (a - b).(a - b),  Assumptions -> assumptions1]

(* Out: a.a + 2 a.b + b.b == a.a - 2 a.b + b.b *)
```

The second is:

```
assumptions2 = {a, b} \[Element] Vectors[2, Reals];
TensorReduce[(a + b).(a + b) == (a - b).(a - b), Assumptions -> assumptions2]

(* Out: (a + b).(a + b) == (a - b).(a - b) *)
```

but, I think, `assumptions1 == assumptions2`.

Why do the two expressions return different results?

Comment: I think `assumption2` means a vector `{a,b}` belongs to `Vectors[2, Reals]` so a&b are numbers, `assumption1` means `a` and `b` are vectors.

Comment: Yeah, I tried your thoughts, maybe you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Assumptions -> {a, b} \[Element] Vectors[2, Reals]` means that `{a, b}` is a 2 element vector with real components. For example, [`TensorRank`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorRank) thinks that `a` is a scalar:

```
TensorRank[a, Assumptions -> {a, b} ∈ Vectors[2, Reals]]
```

> 0

and changing the assumption so that the LHS cannot be interpreted as a vector of the desired dimensions produces:

```
{a, b} ∈ Vectors[3, Reals]
{a, b, c} ∈ Vectors[2, Reals]
```

> False
>
> False

To specify that two variables are vectors, use [`Alternatives`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alternatives) instead:

```
TensorRank[a, Assumptions -> (a|b) ∈ Vectors[2, Reals]]
```

> 1